# Android: Dynamically adding textviews to a scrollview

Tags: android-layout, android, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I am working on an application that functions like a text messaging app. I am working on the layout of the app now. In the XML file I have an edit text on the top of the screen and one on the bottom of the screen. I want to dynamically create a scrollview that would be between the 2 edit texts. The scroll view would enable to scroll through multiple messages of the app. When I try to create the scrollview and textview dynamically it replaces the edittexts and they disappear.

So my question is how would I go about preventing the edittexts from disappearing and adding a scrollview in between the 2 edit texts ?

My code is like this:

```
   ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
   LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
   ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
   sv.addview(ll);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Dynamic layouts ftw!");
    ll.addView(tv);
    this.setContentView(sv);
```

Comment: what happen when u are running this code?

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking to do is build a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html). ListView'ss have every function you require and more. Further, with the adapters, they are pretty quick. [Here is a decent turorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) on using ListViews.